# Downloading Fails over 2 GB on HTTP using libcurl

Tags: libcurl

I have written the code, it works for data downloading up to 2 GB. If data is greater than 2GB it wont work..Please tell me the solution as I have found a lot but not get appropriate answer.

I am writing some small code snippet for the reference.It is not the Full Code...
The Destination Target File System is EXT4 I think.

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
m_curl = curl_easy_init();  

curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT,1048L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 30L);

curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {

size_t written;

    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);

curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, NULL);

curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
```

Please give me the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try tryping `curl -V` at the command line. If the resulting text doesn't contain the word `Largefile` then you are using a version of curl that doesn't support file sizes larger than 2 GB.

[This answer has more useful information.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711137/1679849)