# Download large file chunk by chunk with php curl

Tags: php, curl

I need php script for resumable file download from url to server. It should be able to start download, then when it snaps (30 sec- 5 min) resume, and so on until it completes whole file.

There is something similar in perl http://curl.haxx.se/programs/download.txt , but I want to do it in php, I don't know perl.

I think using `CURLOPT_RANGE` to download chunks, and `fopen($fileName, "a")` to append it to file on server.

Here is my try:

```
<?php

function run()
{
    while(1)
    {
         get_chunk($_SESSION['url'], $_SESSION['filename']);
         sleep(5);
         flush();
    }    
}

function get_chunk( $url, $fileName)
{

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    if (file_exists($fileName)) {
        $from = filesize($fileName);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, $from . "-");//maybe "-".$from+1000 for 1MB chunks
    }

    $fp = fopen($fileName, "a");
    if (!$fp) {
        exit;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    fclose($fp);

}

?>
```

Comment: This will be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032924/how-to-partially-download-a-remote-file-with-curl

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to download a file over a flaky connection, `curl` has a `--retry` flag to automatically retry the download in case of error and continue where it left off.  Unfortunately it seems the [PHP library is missing that option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php) because [libcurl is also missing that option](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/symbols-in-versions.html).

Normally I recommend using a library rather than an external command, but rather than rolling your own it may be simpler in this case to just invoke `curl --retry` or `curl -C -` on the command line.  `wget -c` is another option.

Otherwise I don't see the need to always get the data in chunks.  Download as much as you can and if there's an error resume using CURLOPT_RANGE and the file size as you are now.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for chunked file download using PHP, not using curl, but fopen:

```
//set the chunnk size, how much would you like to transfer in one go
$chunksize = 5 * (1024 * 1024);
//open your local file with a+ access (appending to the file = writing at end of file)
$fp = fopen ($local_file_name, 'a+');
if($fp === false)
{
    //error handling, local file cannot be openened
}
else
{
    //open remote file with read permission, you need to have allow_url_fopen to be enabled on our server if you open here a URL
    $handle = fopen($temp_download, 'rb');
    if($handle === false)
    {
        //error handling, remote file cannot be opened
    }
    else
    {
        //while we did not get to the end of the read file, loop
        while (!feof($handle))
        { 
            //read a chunk of the file
            $chunk_info = fread($handle, $chunksize);
            if($chunk_info === false)
            {
                //error handling, chunk reading failed
            }
            else
            {
                //write the chunk info we just read to the local file
                $succ = fwrite($fp, $chunk_info);
                if($succ === false)
                {
                    //error handling, chunk info writing locally failed
                }
            }
        } 
        //close handle
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
//close handle
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could help us to understand what your code does and how it solves the OP's problem!

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas thank you for pointing this out, I added comments to the code