# Write big file from web into local directory with CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE

Tags: php, curl, buffer

There is a big iso file on the web from which i want to write it into my local directory with CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE  as 102400 bytes,so i wrote the following code to do the job.

```
<?php
$url="http://gensho.acc.umu.se/debian-cd/8.0.0/i386/iso-cd/debian-8.0.0-i386-lxde-CD-1.iso";
$ch=curl_init();
$a_opt=array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 102400
        );
curl_setopt_array($ch,$a_opt);
$str=curl_exec($ch);
$f=fopen('/tmp/debian.iso','w');
fwrite($f,$str)
?>
```

Maybe there are some bugs in it,but no error ouput,i can't download the target iso file,how to fix it?

Comment: See the response in the network. It doesn't wait for the request..

Answer (score 0):

Try to set TIMEOUT and CONNECTTIMEOUT options. 
Try to debug you code using 
`var_dump($str)`;
and

```
curl_error($ch);
```

Reading of [How to partially download a remote file with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032924/how-to-partially-download-a-remote-file-with-curl) might be useful.

Comment: I mean CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT options,  
max_execution_time=0 set unlimited execution time of entire script only.