# php download from url in multi chunk at the same time

Tags: php, fopen, php-curl

Because of connection speed limit for each request, i can't download large file from my remote server(getting timeout), but when testing with multi connection at same time(test with download managers software) download speed incredibly and get completed.
I tested `cUrl` and `fopen` but none of this has multi chunk download at same time.

Tips: I don't need download multi file at same time, something like https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl

Answer (score 0):

cUrl has an option called range that makes partial download of a file possible. 
You can refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) for more information about range and see a sample PHP cUrl request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032924/how-to-partially-download-a-remote-file-with-curl)

For running a multi_curl refer to [this](https://riptutorial.com/php/example/13221/using-multi-curl-to-make-multiple-post-requests)

Comment: thanks, but with range, you can't download multi connection simultaneously. just can download part of file.

Comment: @MaryamBagheri check the last link.